# KML to SqlGeography

Tags: c#, google-maps-api-3, kml, sqlgeography

Anyone have a function or DLL that will convert KML to SqlGeography (SQLServer DataType)?

I'll write it out myself if i have to, but i'm surprised i can't find one out there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created a project to do it when I had this problem. I've got it open sourced now. (https://github.com/pharylon/kml2sql). If it isn't exactly what you need, SharpKML is a great library for getting started on your own project. (http://sharpkml.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Other people have had this problem. There are solutions but they are generally overkill. Here is a lighter solution:

http://consultingblogs.emc.com/stevewright/archive/2009/01/23/how-to-load-spatial-data-into-sql-server-2008-from-net.aspx

Comment: The link seems to be broken